# why i can not update data using vuex module?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules, vuex-module-decorators

here is my component

```
     methods:{
         ...mapActions(['udpateUsers']),
         Update(userID){
             let formData = new FormData();
             formData.append('new_name',this.editUser.new_name);
             formData.append('_method', 'PUT');      
             let config = {
                 headers:{
                     'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',         
                 }        
             }
             this.udpateUsers(userID,formData,config);
         }
```

when i click update button the formData can not be sent to the server but when i console it the FormData is has all the fields

here is my modules

```
        mutations:{
             ADD_USER: (state,response)=>{
                 state.Users = response;
             },
             UPDATE_USERS: (state,response)=>{
                 state.Users = response;
             }
         },
         actions:{
             udpateUsers: ({commit},userID,formData,config)=>{  
                     http.put("/admin/update/"+userID,formData,config)
                     .then((response)=>{
                         commit("UPDATE_USERS",formData);  
                         console.log(response);
                     })
                     .catch((error)=>{
                         console.log(error.response);
                    })
             }
         }
     export default auth
```

i think the error will be my commit mutation

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass multiple parameters as payload to Vuex Actions. You'll need to wrap it all up in an object and pass it as a single param.

```js
udpateUsers: ({commit}, { userID, formData, config }) => {
    // send to backend
}
```

```js
this.udpateUsers({ userID, formData, config });
```

EDIT: From comments, it seems that you're using PUT method instead of POST in your VueX implementation, which is why your backend wasnt getting the data.

Comment: udpateUsers: ({commit},{userID,formData,config})=>{
                http.put("/admin/update/"+userID,formData,config)
                .then((response)=>{
                    commit("UPDATE_USERS",formData,config);
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error.response);
                })
                
        }

Comment: this.udpateUsers({userID,formData,config});

Comment: in backend i'm gonna return all request but data not found

Comment: {data: Array(0), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: '/admin/update/47', method: 'put', data: FormData, headers: {…}, baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api', …}
data: []
headers: {cache-control: 'no-cache, private', content-type: 'application/json'}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: when i try not to use vuex it's working fine

Comment: import http from '@/axiosAPI/axios.js';

Comment: http.post("/admin/update/"+userID,formData,config)
                .then((response)=>{
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error.response);
                })

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? What do you mean by "data not found"? Is the formdata empty in request? What output do you get if you log Formdata at various places in your code - before making http request, before the commit, inside the mutation?

Comment: When i console before commit the formData is has all fields i input but when i commit the form data is empty to the backend.

Comment: If you console formData inside the `updateUsers` action, just before the http request, what do you get? What do you get if you console inside `.then` after getting the response? Also could you please add to your question the code that seems to be working (without VueX)?

Comment: can u see i comment my self above?

Comment: Are you using PUT request or POST request? In your question you're using http.put, but in comments above you've written http.post. Maybe that could be the problem. I don't see any issue with the VueX code, I think the problem is definitely in your request or some typo in your codes when using with VueX.

Comment: Yes you're right brother now i use post method it's working now thank you so much brother i really happy now ;) ;) ;) thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :) I've edited the answer to include your problem. Please could you accept the answer.

Comment: oh brother i have another question, all the action (post,put,delete,get) do we must have to commit all the time?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do with each of those actions. Seems to me like it should be a different question.